# Javascript inline DOM change event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've have a html input field like:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldName" onChange="alert(1)" />
```

`onChange` event does not trigger on DOM change. Is there any way to detect all changes inline as like `onChange` mentioned above?

Comment: Try `onInput`, though to be honest, you should avoid using event attributes altogether.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what and on which element do you want to detect the DOM change?

Comment: Are you expecting the onChange to be triggered on any change to the DOM?

Comment: I think this could be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

I don't post answer because I don't want down votes.

Comment: I think there are some more events to listen changes . 1. <input type="text" name="fieldName" onkeypress="alert(1)" /> 2.  <input type="text" name="fieldName" onkeydown="alert(1)" /> 3. <input type="text" name="fieldName" onkeyup="alert(1)" />

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is either a) bad practice or b) possible, but in a way that you don't want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

With textbox you should use either `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` instead of `onchange` because `onchange` is triggered only when the textbox is blurred.

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" onkeydown="callme(this);" /> <br />

function callme(obj) {
    alert(obj.name); 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't like to touch the field as I'm not inserting the value manually.

Comment: @Rejaul what you mean by you cannot touch.You should use the events as I said.onchange will not work here would that be select box it would work.

Comment: Sorry. I don't like to select the field manually. Value of this field will be given from javascript.